# django admin: custom app_index with context

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

In django admin, we can define custom templates per app. In this case, I'm customising the `app_index.html` template for my application.

I'd like to add a few graphs and other to that page. Now that I've overridden the template, how can I override the corresponding view method?

I thought about making a custom `AdminSite` and override the `app_index()`  (see https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L511) method, but I have more than one application in my django installation, all of which will have a custom `app_index.html`.

What's the best way to add context to the `app_index.html` template?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the best way, but it can be done with template
tags. Here is how I did it:

```
# <app>/templatetags/erp.py
register = template.Library()
@register.assignment_tag
def erp_get_tasks ():
    return Task.objects.exclude (done=True).order_by ('priority')
```

.

```
# <app>/templates/admin/erp/app_index.html
{% extends "admin/app_index.html" %}
{% load erp %}
...
{% block footer %}
{% erp_get_tasks as tasks %}
{% for task in tasks %}
...
```